# Calling the OneLogin API for multiple clients

Tags: api, authorization, onelogin

We are developing an app which will make use of the OneLogin API for multiple clients

We are wanting a customer to be able to Authenticate to OneLogin (through OAuth) and then for us to receive an access token etc

We dont obviously want to ask customers for client id and secret.

Is this possible?